# Excel: How to find values in array, in between specific range

Tags: excel

I am trying to take, in Excel, from an array the values that are in a specific range.

For now I have the followings:

I have generated 500 unique values from 1 to 16384 =UNIQUE(RANDARRAY(500,1,1,16384,TRUE))
I have managed to take all the values, from the array that are smaller or equal than 2048 =SORT(IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,SMALL(IF($B:$B<=2048,ROW($B:$B)),ROW())),""))
What I am trying to do next is to take, from the same array, all the values that are in between 2049 and 4096.

Can somebody explain what function to use instead of SMALL or how to treat the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you already got rid of values under 2048, then get rid of values over 4096. Remaining values will be what you are searching

Comment: Many thanks! The idea is that I want to extract, in cascade, the values. First, the ones <=2048, then the ones in between (2049, 4096], (4097, 6144] and so on until I reach 16384.

Comment: Where are the results supposed to go? Each group into a separate column?

Comment: Yes, in separat columns.

Comment: Do you actually have Excel 365 (as use of sort etc. would imply) or Excel 2010?

Comment: And have you converted the return from your `RANDARRAY` formula to values? Otherwise, I have a feeling that any solution which attempts to reference that range will result in (perhaps intermittent) `#SPILL!` errors. For example, what does the formula `=FILTER(A1#,A1#<=2048)`. where I'm assuming `A1` contains your `RANDARRAY` formula, return for you? I get a `#SPILL!` error on recalculating with F9 about 9 times out of every 10.

Comment: I am using Excel 365. I have not converted the return from randarray formula to values.

Comment: And did you carry out the test I suggested?

Comment: Dear, I have converted the the return values from my array to values and for the first condition it works perfectly. Now, when I am trying to verify in between 2 values I get the error #CALC!. This is what I tried to do:  =FILTER(B$5:B$500,AND(B$5:B$500>2048,B$5:B$500<4096)). Do you have any suggestion on how to deal with it?